# XAML Vertical Scrolling Grid within a Horizontal ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to recreate the layout of the Weather app in XAML / C#. I have a `ListView` full of ListViewItems. It is one of several objects within a `ScrollViewer`. The end result should be that the user can scroll horizontally through the Objects, but stop on the ListView and scroll vertically.

For the effect to work, the `ScrollViewer` must match the height of the page, and the `ListView` must match the height of the `ScrollViewer`, without stretching it.

I can't figure out how to do this without using code-behind to find the `Window.Current.Bounds` and apply the height to the `ScrollViewer`, this seems like a dirty hack. Is there a way to do this purely in XAML?

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` has its own scrollbar stuff, without needing a ScrollViewer. Otherwise to make things stretch it should be pretty easy - how are you putting things in the ScrollViewer? Through a `Grid`? A `StackPanel`?

Comment: It Should be pretty easy alright. But it isn't. The Hierarchy goes ScrollViewer > Grid > ListView and Siblings

Comment: Does this not work?
    `<ScrollViewer>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
            
            <Something Grid.Column="0"/>
            <ListView Grid.Column="1">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`

Comment: `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
            <Something Grid.Column="2" />
        </ScrollViewer>`

@roryok

Comment: There are a few small mistakes in that XAML (grid is closed too early, ListView.View isn't a valid element - should be ListViewItem I guess?) but even when those are corrected this does not work for me.

Comment: @roryok oops, yeah, forgot the `</Grid>`. That's weird that `ListView.View` doesn't exist for you though... maybe it's a metro thing? And what's "not working" about it? Does it not compile, nothing shows up...?

Comment: If I replace the `ListView` and `Something` with my elements, it compiles and appears much like what I've already built. However, it doesn't allow horizontal scrolling at all.

Comment: Did you tell the `ScrollViewer` to show the scrollbars? Maybe they're turned off by default for some crazy reason

Comment: Makes no difference if I turn them on or off.

Comment: I'm all out of ideas then, sorry :/

Comment: =( I'll keep trying and post if I find an answer

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for, but you may find it useful to achieve a 'weather app' look and feel:

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/a-winrt-behavior-to-turn-flipview-into.html